# Python Google Search: Hits within date range are inaccurate

Tags: python, search, google-search, date-range, hit-count

I've been trying to write code to scrape the number of hits within a certain date range on google. I've done this by inserting the date into the google search query. When I copy and paste the link it produces, it gives me the correct query, but when the code runs it, I keep getting the number of hits for the search without the date range. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from datetime import date, timedelta


day = date.today()
friday = day - timedelta(days=day.weekday() + 3) + timedelta(days=7)

word = "debt"

for n in range(0,32,7):
    date_end = friday - timedelta(days=n)
    date_beg = date_end - timedelta(days=4)

    link_beg = "https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%%3A1%%2Ccd_min%%3A" % (word)
    link_date = "%s%%2F%s%%2F%s%%2Ccd_max%%3A%s%%2F%s%%2F%s&tbm=&gws_rd=ssl" % (str(date_beg.month),str(date_beg.day),str(date_beg.year),str(date_end.month),str(date_end.day),str(date_end.year))

    url = link_beg + link_date

    print url,
    print "\t",
    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    products = soup.findAll("div", id = "resultStats")

    result = str(products[0])
    results = re.findall(r'\d+', result)

    number = ''.join([str(i) for i in results])

    print number
```

For example, one of the links that is produced is this:

[Google Search for "debt" in date range "3/9/2015 to 3/13/2015"](https://www.google.com/search?q=debt&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A3%2F9%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A3%2F13%2F2015&tbm=&gws_rd=ssl)

The hits produced should be: 39,700,000

But instead, it spits out: 293,000,000 (which is what just a generic search produces)

Answer (score 0):

Google's date range limited search relies on Julian dates-- i.e. the range must be specified in Julian nomenclature. Perhaps you realized this already.

cute kitties daterange:[some Julian date]-[another Julian date] (without brackets).

There are web pages to convert to Julian, or use the jDate Python script or jday shell script.